# Trace Application

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# Windows Application. It has tab control implemented. My requirement is to trace events such as a method entry/exit, program load, etc and transfer these values to a textBox (named as traceTextBox) in one of the tabs.

I will be happy if anyone can guide me as to where to start from.

I want to trace only events: button click and method entry and exit.

I want to trace events in my applications only.

I want only trace and not debug events.

**Please note:** I do not want to log to a text file or the console. I want the output to be updated in a textbox.

Comment: @user187023: Do you want to trace all events without having to manually subscribe/write event handlers yourself, or are you okay with writing handlers for everything you want to trace?

Answer (score 2):

`System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` is your friend.  You can then create a subclass of `System.Diagnostics.TraceListener` and register it by adding it to  `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceListeners` so that your code receives notification of these events.

Note that the trace events will only be compiled into the code when the `TRACE` conditional compilation flag is set (usually by adding it to the 'Conditional Compilation Symbols' box in each relevant project's settings).

---

```
public sealed class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    public MyTraceListener() : base("MyTraceListener")
    {
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        //TODO code here to add to your UI element

        //NOTE make sure you hand off to the UI thread e.g.
        //     using InvokeRequired/Invoke
    }
}
```

In your application startup:

```
...
Trace.Listeners.Add(new MyTraceListener());
...
```

Writing traces:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Entered SomeMethod()");

    //...

    Trace.WriteLine("Exited SomeMethod()");
}
```